# How to accept multiple date formats for date field in webform module (with and without leading zeros)?

Tags: 8, webforms, datetime

I have webform created with webform module. Inside it I have date field which should accept person's date of birth. When I edit that filed I can set date format at "Date settings" section, "Date format" field.

Problem is that I can set only one format there. I.e. if I set custom format to:

```
j.n.Y
```

it will accept days and months only without leading zeros. I can change it of course to accept with leading zeros, but then if someone enters day / month without leading zero it won't pass validation.

Is there a way to set date field somehow so form will accept both options - with and without leading zeros?

Comment: You could implement a datepicker to solve the inconsistent formatting problem.

Comment: Yes, my idea also, but client doesn't like it.

Comment: You could try, for example, to reformat when it has zeros to no zeros in a custom validation function that runs before the default validation function.